# login logout twitter account framework iOS with multiple account

Tags: iphone, ios, twitter, account

i want know how i can manage multiple twitter account on iOS in my app, i know that in this way:

```
ACAccountStore *accountStore = [[ACAccountStore alloc] init];
ACAccountType *accountType = [accountStore accountTypeWithAccountTypeIdentifier:ACAccountTypeIdentifierTwitter];

[accountStore requestAccessToAccountsWithType:accountType withCompletionHandler:^(BOOL granted, NSError *error) {
    if(granted) {
        NSArray *accountsArray = [accountStore accountsWithAccountType:accountType];

        ACAccount *twitterAccount = [accountsArray objectAtIndex:0];

    }
}];
```

i can retrieve the twitter account, but how i can let the user choose what twitter account use in my app, and login logout to select another account?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The Accounts framework only provides for one Twitter account. You can probably work directly with [Twitter's API](https://dev.twitter.com/) to handle multiple accounts in your app, but you won't be able to make use of iOS's built-in Twitter framework for that.

Comment: That's not true. You can select account.

Comment: @SeptiadiAgus You should point out how to do that before you down vote him!